# Folder Size - File System

Tags: javascript, node.js, sistema-de-arquivos

Estou tentando pegar o tamanho da pasta que está meu projeto, a pasta se chama `Testes`, e no meu arquivo `server.js` eu estou usando o seguinte método:

```
fs.stat('/Testes', function(err,stats){
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(null, stats.size); 
  })
```

Mas está sempre me retornando `null, 0` e não o tamanho real da pasta, esqueci alguma coisa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso em Node.js não é muito simples. Há outras plataformas que são "mais especializadas" na parte de ficheiros.

Mas de qq maneira cá fica, a ideia é ir ler uma diretoria e a cada entrada dessa diretoria somar o tamanho dessa entrada. Se a entrada for uma diretoria, corre o mesmo codigo recursivamente.

Ficaria assim:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const folder = process.argv[2];

function getAllFiles(folder) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(folder, (err, files) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      const filesWithPath = files.map(f => path.join(folder, f));
      Promise.all(filesWithPath.map(getFileSize)).then(sizes => {
        const sum = sizes.reduce(addValues, 0);
        resolve(sum);
      });
    });
  });
}

function getFileSize(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.stat(file, (err, stat) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      if (stat.isDirectory()) getAllFiles(file).then(resolve);
      else resolve(stat.size);
    });
  });
}

function addValues(sum, val) {
  return sum + val;
}

function formatBytes(bytes) {
  if (bytes < 1024) return bytes + " Bytes";
  else if (bytes < 1048576) return (bytes / 1024).toFixed(3) + " Kb";
  else if (bytes < 1073741824) return (bytes / 1048576).toFixed(3) + " Mb";
  else return (bytes / 1073741824).toFixed(3) + " GB";
}

getAllFiles(folder)
  .then(sum => {
    console.log(`O tamanho da diretoria "${folder}" é`, formatBytes(sum));
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

E para usar podes fazer (assumindo que `getSize.js` é o nome do ficheiro com o script acima):

```
node getSize.js ./lib
```